# Why isn't 1/2 a limit point of sequence $X_n = 1/n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

There's one confusion I have been having regarding Limit points of a sequence.
The definition dictates that $p$ is called a limit point of a sequence $(X_n)$ if every neighborhood of $p$ contains infinitely many terms of the given sequence.

I took one example.
$$X_n = \frac{1}{n}$$

Can someone give me an example of a neighborhood of 1/2 that doesn't contain infinitely many terms of the sequence? I know this sequence only has one limit point which is 0 but I want examples as to why the other members of the sequence can't be called limit points.

Please help guys

Answer (score 5):

$(\frac 1 2 -\frac 1 6, \frac 1 2 -\frac 1 6)$ does not contain $X_n$ for any $n \neq 2$.

More generally, $(\frac 1 n-\frac 1 {n(n+1)},\frac 1 n-\frac 1 {n(n+1)})$ is an interval around $X_n$ which contains no other $X_m$. So $X_n$ is not a limit point for any $n$.

Comment: Yes, I got it now. Just one more thing, sorry for pretty novice questions but I am just starting out. How do we prove that every neighborhood of 0 will contain infinitely many terms of the sequence?

Comment: Ofc this is a convergent sequence and so we can say the limit of this sequence will be its only limit point. But other than this, how do we prove it ?

Comment: Any neighbourhood of $0$ contains $(0,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon >0$ and $\frac 1n$ is in this interval for all $n >\frac 1 {\epsilon}$. @RandomlyReal

Comment: @RandomlyReal I have edited my answer to show that $X_n$ is not a limit point for any $n$. Yes,  $0$ is the only limit point of the sequence.

Comment: @RandomlyReal this is the Archimedean property in disguise.

Answer (score 1):

Definition of limit points: Let $A \subseteq X$ Then, $x \in X$ is a limit point of $A$ iff
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists y \in A: |x - y| < \epsilon \land y \neq x
$$

That is, any open ball centered at $x$ has at least one element of $A$ different from $x$.

If we choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}$, there is no element different from $\frac{1}{2}$ whose distance from $\frac{1}{2}$ is less than $\epsilon$. So, there cannot be a subsequence that converges to $\frac{1}{2}$.